# Print taxonomy term for theming nodes

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms

I'm not a PHP developer, so I have a problem with customizing a theme.

I create a vocabulary "City" and a term "Shiraz", then a field "field_city" as a taxonomy term in my content type.

Now I want to print this field, so in the tpl file I write the following code:

```
<?php print render($content['field_city']); ?>
```

but nothing happens.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out :

1. Make sure you set the right display of the field, like the following picture.[image]
2. loop through `Items` and render vocab fields.

```php
<?php foreach ($content['field_city']['#items'] as $item): ?>
   <?php print render($item['taxonomy_term']->name); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Note** : print only `name` field, if you have another fields in your vocabulary add them, like `$item['taxonomy_term']->some_field`